# Decompose an Integer in sum of integers containing only 1,2,3 as its digit

Tags: dynamic-programming, discrete-mathematics

I was struggling with a problem on Atcoder, in which we have to find minimum K for a number N such that K numbers of whose digits are either 1, 2, or 3 can sum up to N.
Through editorial, I could only understand, if

```
p is good if p = 10a + b
```

where a is either 0 or a is itself that kind of number and b is either 1, 2, or 3.
from this point onward, I'm not able under how to proceed further and what the author is meant by a good number. This problem seems really delicate but its solution is bizarre. Also, give me a better solution if possible.

problem link: https://atcoder.jp/contests/arc123/tasks/arc123_c

Comment: The answer seems to be: (1) if all digits are between 1 and 3 (2) if all digits are between 2 and 6. (3) if all digits are between 3 and 9 (4) otherwise. I've yet to find any example that needs 5, but this property probably needs a formal proof.

Comment: @user3257842: 413 needs 5.

Comment: Correct. I made a mistake in my assumptions. Another example would be 4142. There should be an algorithm to distinguish numbers requiring 4 from the rest. Basically you need to check its ending digits. If the number can't be written as a sum of  (1), (2) or (3), and it ends in a 3, then it needs more than 4. If the number ends in 0, 1 or 2, replace the number by its remainder mod 10, subtract 1 (the carry),and apply the algorithm recursively. This should work to see if it can be written as sum of four.It's based on summing the last digits of the four numbers. Still, would 5 be the upper bound?

Comment: Also if the number isn't ending in 0, 1 or 2 or 3, just replace the number with its remainder mod 10 without subtracting 1.